# Finding duplicate items then selecting one with closest date to currentDate

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

**Note:** Using Windows Mobile 6.5 Compact Framework.

I have a collection of the following object.

```
public class RFileModel
{
    public List<string> RequiredFilesForR = new List<string>();
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string RouteId { get; set; }
}

var ListOfRFileModels = new List<RFileModel>();
```

There is the chance that the same `RouteId` will be in multiple instances of `RFileModel` but with a different `Date`.

I'm trying to identify the duplicates and select only one, the one closest to the current date.

I have the following LINQ so far:

```
var query =  ListOfRFileModels.GroupBy(route => route.RouteId)
                              .OrderBy(newGroup => newGroup.Key)
                              .Select(newGroup => newGroup).ToList();
```

But I don't think this is what I need, since it still returns all elements. I was expecting a list of non unique `RouteId`, that way I can iterate each non-unique id and compare dates to see which one to keep.

How can I accomplish this with LINQ or just plain ole `foreach`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression sorts groups, not group elements. Here is how to fix it:

```
DateTime currentDate = ...
var query =  ListOfRFileModels
    .GroupBy(route => route.RouteId)
    .Select(g => g.OrderBy(fm => currentDate-fm.Date).First())
    .ToList();
```

`currentDate-fm.Date` expression produces the difference between the current date and the date of the `RFileModel` object. The object with the smallest difference would end up in the first position of the ordered sequence. The call `First()` picks it up from the group to produce the final result.

Comment: Works great; It returned the full list, and for duplicates of route 6001, it only included the one with date closest to today! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want ONLY the members with duplicates, take @dasblinkenlight's answer and add a Where clause: `.Where(grp => grp.Count()>1)`:

```
DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now;
var query =  ListOfRFileModels
   .GroupBy(route => route.RouteId)
   .Where(grp => grp.Count()>1)
   .Select(g => g.OrderBy(fm => currentDate-fm.Date).First())
   .ToList();
```